# GPUImage: Reducing color depth

Tags: pixel, gpuimage, color-depth

I would like to reduce the color depth of input video and images (for example, to 16bit) when using GPUImage on iOS, and was just curious if there is a simple way to do this using existing filters.

It looks like GPUImageColorMatrixFilter or GPUImageRGBFilter might be the right tools; is this the case?  I will start experimenting now, as well.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think either of those are going to do what you want here. Ignoring dithering, you're going to want something that reduces the number of color levels in your image.

The GPUImagePosterizeFilter reduces color levels by reducing the dynamic range of the red, green, and blue channels individually using the `colorLevels` property. For a value of 10, that should reduce your image to a 1000-color one.

However, because this acts on each color channel individually and uniformly, this may not reduce your colorspace in the specific way that you'd want. To tune colorspace reductions like this, I've seen people use color mapping tables. If you want to go that way, I'd recommend the GPUImageLookupFilter, where you can do your reduction operation on a lookup table image and then use that to do your remapping. This might lead to a higher-quality result.

Comment: Thanks; still experimenting with it - will reply later with results.